# Store multiple objects into one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a angular/rails app in which users can search for a movie, and then add that movie to their watchlist.

This is the create function in angular,

```
createMovie.create({
  release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
  imdb_rating:    $scope.movieImdbRating.imdbRating,
  title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
  image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
  movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id,
  backdrop:       $scope.movieListID.backdrop_path,
  crew:           $scope.movieCrew = response.credits.crew,
  cast:           $scope.movieCast = response.credits.cast
}).then(init);
```

And I have the cast and crew data in a scope,

```
$scope.movieCrew = response.credits.crew
$scope.movieCast = response.credits.cast
```

These scopes return multple objects, since there are multiple actors etc. involved.

I have a movies_controller.rb that has a create function like this,

```
def create
   @movie = Movie.find_or_create_by movie_params
   current_user.movies << @movie
   redirect_to :root
   current_user.followers.each { |follower| @movie.crete_activity(key: 'movie.create', owner: current_user, recipient: follower) }
end

private
def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(
    :title,
    :image,
    :imdb_rating,
    :release_date,
    :movie_id,
    :backdrop
    :crew,
    :cast
  )
end
```

My movie model looks like this,

```
create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "release_date"
  t.string   "image"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.string   "movie_id"
  t.string   "backdrop"
  t.string   "crew"
  t.string   "cast"
end
```

When I run the action the movie record gets created

```
{"id":26,"title":"The Neon Demon","release_date":"2016-01-21","image":"/gVB7zbrsk9TtLoVI4qob97q9v07.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2016-01-07T12:31:49.956Z","updated_at":"2016-01-07T12:31:49.956Z","movie_id":"301365","backdrop":"/lSojrYBHLwiQQq6xr9Mec9f8wLM.jpg","crew":null,"cast":null}
```

But the crew and cast values are empty.

I've checked my rails console to see what happens when the movie is created,

```
Started POST "/movies.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-07 13:31:49 +0100
Processing by MoviesController#create as JSON

  Parameters: {
    "release_date"=>"2016-01-21", 
    "imdb_rating"=>"N/A", 
    "title"=>"The Neon Demon", 
    "image"=>"/gVB7zbrsk9TtLoVI4qob97q9v07.jpg", 
    "movie_id"=>301365, 
    "backdrop"=>"/lSojrYBHLwiQQq6xr9Mec9f8wLM.jpg",

    "crew"=>[
      {"credit_id"=>"54881a95c3a368415c000cde", "department"=>"Directing", id"=>21183, job"=>"Director", name"=>"Nicolas Winding Refn", profile_path"=>"/tFqRY5LgXH6W9GV51xCiJS1y8mB.jpg"}, 
      {"credit_id"=>"54881a9c925141520a000c5b", department"=>"Writing", id"=>21183, job"=>"Screenplay", name"=>"Nicolas Winding Refn", profile_path"=>"/tFqRY5LgXH6W9GV51xCiJS1y8mB.jpg"}, 
      {"credit_id"=>"54881ac8c3a368414d000fd8", department"=>"Writing", ""=>1397141, job"=>"Screenplay", name"=>"Mary Laws", profile_path"=>nil}, 
      {"credit_id"=>"54881ad792514151ff000e94", department"=>"Camera", id"=>63422, job"=>"Director of Photography", name"=>"Philippe Le Sourd",         "profile_path"=>nil}, 
      {"credit_id"=>"54881ae5c3a3684148000cc8", department"=>"Sound", id"=>8377, job"=>"Original Music Composer", name"=>"Cliff Martinez", 
      "profile_path"=>nil}, 
      {"credit_id"=>"56424bf5c3a3686a5800064e", department"=>"Editing", id"=>966286, job"=>"Editor", name"=>"Matthew Newman", profile_path"=>nil}
      ], 

    "cast"=>[
      {"cast_id"=>5, "character"=>"Jesse", "credit_id"=>"54cd541dc3a3687f8f002102", "id"=>18050, "name"=>"Elle Fanning", "order"=>1, "profile_path"=>"/ouQIwOEVvyDzsU5j0Iw4oRIuGW4.jpg"}, 
      {"cast_id"=>6, "character"=>"Sarah", "credit_id"=>"54cd5425925141475700204d", "id"=>1036288, "name"=>"Abbey Lee", "order"=>2, "profile_path"=>"/tCLVClLA2dB43KdyqJusmcuvvEC.jpg"}, 
      {"cast_id"=>7, "character"=>"", "credit_id"=>"54d3a598c3a3686abf003f08", "id"=>20089, "name"=>"Jena Malone", "order"=>3, "profile_path"=>"/tx5KR6dAhYag3plX7Rdg8t25QrC.jpg"}, 
      {"cast_id"=>8, "character"=>"", "credit_id"=>"54d3a59c9251413fc1003e39", "id"=>6384, "name"=>"Keanu Reeves", "order"=>4, "profile_path"=>"/glCFGnKkX3QWxeLRYUMU1XTESHf.jpg"}, 
      {"cast_id"=>9, "character"=>"", "credit_id"=>"54d3a5a59251413fc1003e3b", "id"=>110014, "name"=>"Christina Hendricks", "order"=>5, "profile_path"=>"/4pAtKssXy84DzJOgl5155KJNS5z.jpg"}, 
      {"cast_id"=>10, "character"=>"", "credit_id"=>"54d3a5ad9251413fd6003e88", "id"=>234982, "name"=>"Bella Heathcote", "order"=>6, "profile_path"=>"/iqk9bZnrkLhIQbHPyrGcMK0Bzni.jpg"}
      ], 

    "movie"=>{
      "title"=>"The Neon Demon", 
      "release_date"=>"2016-01-21", 
      "image"=>"/gVB7zbrsk9TtLoVI4qob97q9v07.jpg", 
      "movie_id"=>301365, 
      "backdrop"=>"/lSojrYBHLwiQQq6xr9Mec9f8wLM.jpg", 

      "crew"=>[
        {"credit_id"=>"54881a95c3a368415c000cde", "department"=>"Directing", "id"=>21183, "job"=>"Director", "name"=>"Nicolas Winding Refn", "profile_path"=>"/tFqRY5LgXH6W9GV51xCiJS1y8mB.jpg"}, 
        {"credit_id"=>"54881a9c925141520a000c5b", "department"=>"Writing", "id"=>21183, "job"=>"Screenplay", "name"=>"Nicolas Winding Refn", "profile_path"=>"/tFqRY5LgXH6W9GV51xCiJS1y8mB.jpg"}, 
        {"credit_id"=>"54881ac8c3a368414d000fd8", "department"=>"Writing", "id"=>1397141, "job"=>"Screenplay", "name"=>"Mary Laws", "profile_path"=>nil}, {"credit_id"=>"54881ad792514151ff000e94", "department"=>"Camera", "id"=>63422, "job"=>"Director of Photography", "name"=>"Philippe Le Sourd", "profile_path"=>nil}, 
        {"credit_id"=>"54881ae5c3a3684148000cc8", "department"=>"Sound", "id"=>8377, "job"=>"Original Music Composer", "name"=>"Cliff Martinez", "profile_path"=>nil}, 
        {"credit_id"=>"56424bf5c3a3686a5800064e", "department"=>"Editing", "id"=>966286, "job"=>"Editor", "name"=>"Matthew Newman", "profile_path"=>nil}
      ], 

      "cast"=>[
        {"cast_id"=>5, "character"=>"Jesse", "credit_id"=>"54cd541dc3a3687f8f002102", "id"=>18050, "name"=>"Elle Fanning", "order"=>1, "profile_path"=>"/ouQIwOEVvyDzsU5j0Iw4oRIuGW4.jpg"}, 
        {"cast_id"=>6, "character"=>"Sarah", "credit_id"=>"54cd5425925141475700204d", "id"=>1036288, "name"=>"Abbey Lee", "order"=>2, "profile_path"=>"/tCLVClLA2dB43KdyqJusmcuvvEC.jpg"}, 
        {"cast_id"=>7, "character"=>"", "credit_id"=>"54d3a598c3a3686abf003f08", "id"=>20089, "name"=>"Jena Malone", "order"=>3, "profile_path"=>"/tx5KR6dAhYag3plX7Rdg8t25QrC.jpg"}, 
        {"cast_id"=>8, "character"=>"", "credit_id"=>"54d3a59c9251413fc1003e39", "id"=>6384, "name"=>"Keanu Reeves", "order"=>4, "profile_path"=>"/glCFGnKkX3QWxeLRYUMU1XTESHf.jpg"}, 
        {"cast_id"=>9, "character"=>"", "credit_id"=>"54d3a5a59251413fc1003e3b", "id"=>110014, "name"=>"Christina Hendricks", "order"=>5, "profile_path"=>"/4pAtKssXy84DzJOgl5155KJNS5z.jpg"}, 
        {"cast_id"=>10, "character"=>"", "credit_id"=>"54d3a5ad9251413fd6003e88", "id"=>234982, "name"=>"Bella Heathcote", "order"=>6, "profile_path"=>"/iqk9bZnrkLhIQbHPyrGcMK0Bzni.jpg"}
      ]
    }
  }
```

As you can see the `parameters` have the correct values, release_date, title, image, crew, cast etc. But it does not store the objects inside them. Also I'm unsure why there's a `movie` value in the `parameters` value that repeats all the data exept for `imdbRating`.

So my question is, how do I store the objects from crew and cast into the my movie record?

Comment: you need to tell strong params to accept cast and crew like a hash, something like crew: %i(credit_id department ... other attrs) and then check out json type of data of AR, otherwise you can create separate object of cast or crew and make relation between movie and them

Comment: try nested_attributes for reference http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @dsounded Could you give a bit more information on your suggestion? I can't make much of it.

Comment: The question is: do you want to store crews and casks with the movie or separately ?@PeterBoomsma

Comment: @dsounded It it is possible I want to store all the information (crew, cast, movie info) into one record.

Comment: See this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json but it's only possible in postgre

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Could you expand a bit on your suggestion? I've tried reading through the documentation but I can't make much of it.